# Как вывести самое повторяющееся число с помощью mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x

новичок в питоне, не понимаю как можно осуществить следующую задачу: нужно вывести самое часто повторяющееся число

`def mode(elements: List[object]) -> object:`

`mode([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2])`

функция должна вывести число 2

объясните пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: collections.Counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return max(set(elements), key = elements.count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну, например, вот так:

```
import statistics as st
a=[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2]
st.mode(a)
```